# ipyvolume dose not plot in Jupiter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I installed `ipyvolume` by using `pip install ipyvolume`. I tried to run this example script

```
import ipyvolume
import numpy as np
x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 10000)) 
ipyvolume.quickscatter(x, y, z, size=1, marker="sphere")
```

in jupyter notebook. However, there is an error raised in the terminal:
`404 GET /static/jupyter-threejs.js?v=20181122105324`
and the cell of code just kept running and can't be stopped by the stop button in jupyter notebook.

`ipywidgets` works fine in my jupyter notebook, what could be the reason why `ipyvolume` isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pythreejs is not installed or enabled. That should happen for notebook 5.3 automatically. You can try this:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --sys-prefix --py pythreejs
```